# Проблема с кодировкой php

Tags: php, charset

Есть строка русская, пытаюсь вывести, выводит: Р°Р°С‹РІ

```
$customer  = 'ааыв';
echo $customer;// Р°Р°С‹РІ
```

Кодировка файла должна быть строго windows-1251. Какими функциями можно принудительно перекодировать строку, что бы выводило 'ааыв'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сам файл в `windows-1251`, то возможно стоит браузеру указать какую кодировку использовать:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
```